# Matching the search exactly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use app script to give access to my Google sheet by searching through a webpage. so I don't have to give all the data. the search is based on a specific column and the result can be repeatable on the column itself but the other columns of the same row like price and item are different. with my current code if the user searched part of the name or even one letter the results will be all the data containing this letter .. how do I show the data only if it matched with the input from the user.. so I can avoid someone writing the letters from a to z to collect all the data.

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate()
  .setTitle("WebApp: Search By Password")
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){ 
  var concat = formObject.searchtext;
  var result = "";
  if(concat){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(concat);
  }
  return result;
}


function search(searchtext = 'searchtext') {
  let ar = [];
 var spreadsheetId   = '1aN8VLL4iKhGjmM84qhncG9cQfKigCWscMT-UkdzNhQs'; 
  const names = ['Data', 'Data2'];
  names.forEach((name) => {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(name).getDataRange();
    var data = range.getValues();
    data.forEach(function (f) {
    if (~[f[0]].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push([f[0],f[1],f[2],f[3],f[4],f[5],f[6],f[7],f[8],f[9]]);
      }
      
    });
  });
  return ar;
};
```

my coding knowledge is basic so can you help me

thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to return a result only if the input matches the data in your sheet exactly, change `~[f[0]].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchtext)` to `f[0] === searchtext`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work and no data is showing after the edite

Comment: no its working its working .. thanks a lot

Comment: It works fine for names but if I'm searching for numbers there's no result .. can u help me with that if you don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to provide a proper response to the question, I'm writing this answer as a community wiki since the issue was resolved from the comments section.

Changing `~[f[0]].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchtext)` to `f[0] === searchtext` would work but as you mentioned in comments, it worked for names but no for numbers.

In this case try changing it to `f[0] == searchtext`. Just to give context, using `==` checks if values are equal while `===` checks if both **type** and **value** match. To give you an example and I imagine this is happening in your case, `'1' ===  1` will not match because they're not the same type.

**References:**

[Equality (==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)

[Strict equality (===)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)